# Get the no of consecutive days a Field value is Stale

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I wanted to get to the consecutive number of records a certain field value is stale based on the rates table.
From the below data records 3,4,5 have the same rate as 0.770827 ,so the days the rate is stale is 3 and the prior rate before stale is 0.770886.I would like to get help in writing a query to the no of records that have stale rate and also get to the prior rate of the same as well.In the below sample i am only showing CAD to USD ,but we need the same across different currencies .
Any assistance would be highly helpful.

[image]

Expected Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a gaps and islands problem.

You can use `lag()` to retrieve the previous `rate` for the same currencies tuple, and then do a window sum to define groups of consecutive records with the same rate. Then, you can aggregate the groups, and recover the previous rate using `lag()` again. The last step is to filter on groups that have at least 3 records.

```
select *
from (
    select
        from_cur,
        to_cur,
        rate,
        max(date) max_date,
        lag(rate) over(partition by from_cur, to_cur order by max(date)) lag_rate_grp,
        count(*) cnt
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            sum(case when rate = lag_rate then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by from_date, to_date order by date) grp 
        from (
            select 
                t.*,
                lag(rate) over(partition by from_cur, to_cur order by date) lag_rate
            from mytable t
        ) t
    ) t
    group by from_cur, to_cur, rate, grp
) t
where cnt >= 3
order by from_cur, to_cur, max_date
```

Actually, using the difference between row numbers can save one level of nesting:

```
select *
from (
    select
        from_cur,
        to_cur,
        rate,
        max(date) max_date,
        lag(rate) over(partition by from_cur, to_cur order by max(date)) lag_rate_grp,
        count(*) cnt
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            row_number() over(partition by from_cur, to_cur order by date) rn1,
            row_number() over(partition by from_cur, to_cur, rate order by date) rn2         
        from mytable t
    ) t
    group by from_cur, to_cur, rate, rn1 - rn2
) t
where cnt >= 3
order by from_cur, to_cur, max_date
```

---

If you want only the earliest record per currency tuple, then you can use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select
        from_cur,
        to_cur,
        rate,
        max(date) max_date,
        lag(rate) over(partition by from_cur, to_cur order by max(date)) lag_rate_grp,
        count(*) cnt,
        row_number() over(partition by from_cur, to_cur, case when count(*) >= 3 then 0 else 1 end order by max(date)) rn
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            row_number() over(partition by from_cur, to_cur order by date) rn1,
            row_number() over(partition by from_cur, to_cur, rate order by date) rn2         
        from mytable t
    ) t
    group by from_cur, to_cur, rate, rn1 - rn2
) t
where cnt >= 3 and rn = 1
order by from_cur, to_cur
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick assistance.I may have specified but my require,ent is to get to the first instance where the count>2 .I will try to work on your query to get to my expected output.

Answer (score 2):

When value changes mark row with 1, otherwise 0. Then sum this column (`flg`), you have now consecutive groups (`grp`). Use `grp` to aggregate, count, show min and max dates:

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=386db930c75a0a2cf8c3173b491003b2)</sup>**

```
select to_cur, from_cur, min(dt) dt_from, max(dt) dt_to, rate, count(1) cnt
  from (
    select dt, to_cur, from_cur, rate, 
           sum(flg) over (partition by to_cur, from_cur order by dt) grp
      from (
        select dt, to_cur, from_cur, rate, 
               case lag(rate) over (partition by to_cur, from_cur order by dt) 
                    when rate then 0 else 1 end flg
          from t))
  group by grp, to_cur, from_cur, rate
  order by from_cur, to_cur, min(dt)
```

If you want any specific group after group by add:

```
  having count(1) >= 3
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick assistance.I may have specified but my require,ent is to get to the first instance where the count>2 .I will try to work on your query to get to my expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gap-and-islands problem, but I would solve it just by subtracting a sequence from the date.  And then aggregating:

```
select to_cur, from_cur, rate, min(date), max(date),
       count(*) as days_stale
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by to_cur, from_cur, rate order by date) as seqnum
      from rates r
     ) r
group by (date - seqnum * interval '1' day)
```